# How to refer to a property from another Domain class in custom validator Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hibernate-validator

I am now having a hard time in building my constraints, I have 3 domain classes namely **Hospital, Doctor** and **Patient**, where **Hospital** and **Doctor** has a 1:m relationship  and **Doctor** and **Patient** also has a 1:m relationship. So i was asked to create a dummy data where i have to make 2 different Hospitals with Doctors and Patients. Here's my code for the domain class **Hospital**.

```
class Hospital {
String name
String location

static transients = ['patients']

static hasMany = [doctor: Doctor, patient: Patient]
static constraints = {

    name(blank:false)
    location(blank:false)
    doctor(nullable:false)

}  }
```

--> and here is my code for the domain class **Doctor**.

```
class Doctor {

String name
String specialization

static hasMany = [patient: Patient]
static belongsTo = [hospital: Hospital]

static constraints = {

    name(blank:false)
    specialization(blank:false)
    patient(nullable:true)
    hospital(nullable:false)
} }
```

--> and for the **Patient** domain class

```
class Patient {
String name
String ailment
int age
Date dateAdmit, dateDischarge

static belongsTo = [doctor: Doctor, hospital: Hospital]

static constraints = {

    name(blank:false, maxSize:100)
    ailment(blank:false)
    age(size:1..200)
    dateAdmit(nullable:true)
    dateDischarge(nullable:true)
    doctor(nullable:false)
    hospital(nullable:false)
}}
```

--> I saved 2 hospitals namely **hospitalA** and **hospitalB** with doctors and patients, my problem is i need to make sure that doctor from **hospitalB** can't have a **patient** from **hospitalA** or the doctor and patient must be in the same hospital. i believe i need to do it with custom validator. but i dont know how since i should compare properties from different domain calsses. please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
    doctor(nullable:false, validator: { d, inst ->
        return d.hospital == inst.hospital; 
    })
```